# Set up Dropbox on my remote shell account?

Tags: dropbox, remote

I've got Dropbox set up on my home Ubuntu 16.10. I'd also like Dropbox on my remote shell account(s). How would I set up Dropbox on my shell account(s) and have everything in my Dropbox synced across home and remote? I found [this](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment) description. Is this what I need to do?

Following the link above does seem to give me a Dropbox presence on my remote server shell account. However I need the `dropboxd` to run automatically in the background. I tried this:

```
>~/bin/dropbox.py autostart
```

per the page's advice, and it gave me this:

```
dropbox autostart [y/n]

options:
  n  dropbox will not start automatically at login
  y  dropbox will start automatically at login (default)

Note: May only work on current Ubuntu distributions.
```

... but then I get the prompt back; no waiting for a yes or no. I assume the `dropboxd` hasn't really been started and I'm not really synced. How can I make the `dropboxd` run automatically without doing it manually each time?